# Where to find the latest up-to-date document for Google Play Billing Library?

Tags: in-app-billing, play-billing-library

[The official guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview) for Google Play Billing Library is obsolete as today (2019-12-11).  Many APIs mentioned in the document are no longer available. 
For example, the following sample code no longer works:

```
int responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(flowParams);
```

The latest method definition:

```
BillingResult launchBillingFlow (Activity activity, 
                BillingFlowParams params)
```

[BillingClient.BillingResponse](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.BillingResponse) no longer exists.  One should use [BillingClient.BillingResponseCode](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.BillingResponseCode) that is not mentioned in [the official guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview).

Could anyone offer a link to an up-to-date guide?  I have to be extremely careful in the migration to Google Play Billing Library from t[he deprecated Play Billing with AIDL](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api). In-app-purchase errors can easily upset users understandably.

I am using:

```
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.1.0'
```

Comment: I recently migrated an app from AIDL to the Billing Library and I didn't notice that BillingResponse in the documents had changed to BillingResponseCode. Android Studio autocomplete has already suggested the new one.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that.  I fear any mistake related to in-app billing because such a mistake can cause uproar from users if they lose purchased goods.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_rewarded_products

Comment: @Style-7 That page appears to be obsolete too.

Comment: No, I did by that information

Comment: @Style-7 Are you able to use BillingResponse.OK used by the sample code on that page?  I am unable to resolve it.  Could you tell me the version of your com.android.billingclient:billing?

Comment: Yes it is. 2.0.3 but now 2.1.0

Comment: @Style-7  It is weird that I cannot resolve BillingResponse.OK with 2.1.0,

Comment: is billing_client connected ok?

Comment: @Style-7 Yes, billingClient.startConnection works fine, but I have to use BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK instead of BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK.